# PHP echo list of users from a database depending on category

Tags: php, database, mysqli, while-loop, echo

Depending on the input from checkboxes I'm trying to echo out users in a database based on category in a table linking the users-table with categories. But I only get one result for each category, even though I know there are several users in each category.

I have spent several dies seaching for the correct way to do this, and based upon the many tutoriels and articles out there I thought this method would work. But it does not.
This is the code that doesn't do what I want it to do:

```
function printusers($idcheck, $cat){

    $sqlString = "SELECT userid FROM user_category WHERE categoryid ='$idcheck'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sqlString) or die("Could not search for user id.." . mysqli_error($dbLink));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Make the first user on the list visable
    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $id = $row['userid'];   
        $sqlString = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sqlString) or die("Could not search for user.." . mysqli_error($dbLink));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $name = $row['name'];

        // echo users
        echo "<h2 class=\"browsecategory\">Category: $cat</h2>
                <p class=\"user\">Name: $name</p>\n";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['admins'])){
    printusers(1, "Administrator");
}
```

I have also tried replacing the while loop with a foreach loop, like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  same code as in while loop
}
```

This method echoed out several empty results. The HTML was there, but there was no information from the database. And the number of reults that were echoed was even higher than the number of results that the database should produce.

This is the HTML. A basic checkbox form:

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="admins" id="admins">
    <input type="checkbox" name="users" id="users">
    <input type="checkbox" name="maillist" id="maillist">
    <input type="submit" value="Browse">
</form>
```

Comment: are you letting people choose from multiple categories based on more than one checkbox selected? you'll need to post your HTML form for this. If your checkboxes are not set as an array then that could be a reason.

Comment: plus, you seem to have a variable scope issue

Comment: As per your edit: you have `if(isset($_POST['admin']))` having "admin" in singular form, yet you have `name="admins"` in plural form; typo? Error reporting would have signaled an undefined index admin notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - That should read as `if(isset($_POST['admins']))`

Comment: If that ^ solves it, let me know. If not, then edit your question to reflect the typo.

Comment: yeah, that's a type... I fumbled a bit after copy-pasting it in to my question and wrote that line again. I has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: then as I said earlier, you may have a variable scope issue. I know this is bad practice (using global), but try `function printusers($idcheck, $cat){ global $dbLink` followed by the rest of your code.

Comment: I added gloabl $dbLink; But that gave me an error: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: another thing; what if someone were to check off more than one checkbox; have you made provisions for that, or is that irrelevant? If you're not, then you'd be best using radios, instead of checkboxes.

Comment: and you are connecting using `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO, right? and you wrote *gloabl $dbLink;* you did mean `global`. I just need to make sure here and that you didn't do another typo.

Comment: I want it to be possible to check of several checkboxes

Comment: `function printusers($idcheck, $cat){ global $dbLink;` (rest of code) made a typo. I forgot the semi-colon, try it again.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there should be a semi-colon there. that's what i tried it with

Comment: try it without the function then and hardcoding the values for it. If that works, then it's your function that's failing, including in `printusers(1, "Administrator");`

Comment: Great idea. But that didn't work either

Comment: Are you certain your $dbLink has an appropriate value? You should be connecting to the database and assigning the return value to $dbLink. If $dbLink is NULL then that'll never work.

Comment: Why are you doing the initial fetch_assoc and then seek? Why not just delete those 2 lines and go straight to your loop...